# How to change XML encoding via Java and XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

How to change the XML encoding via Java and XPath? Would like to have "ISO-8859-1".

Thanks!

Comment: do you need to update encoding in xml file or in xmld document that is already unmarshaleld to an object?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what library you are using for serialization.

A common technique is to use the XSLT serializer with a null transformation

```
TransformerFactory.getInstance().getTransformer().transform(DOMSource, StreamResult)
```

which allows you to specify serialization properties (setOutputProperty) on the Transformer object; one of the properties you can set is "encoding".